# Recent Step-by-Step for ActionScript / Flex / AIR with TextMate?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, installation, textmate

i apologize if this post is redundant.

i'm searching unsuccessfully for recent, step-by-step instructions on how to set up ActionScript 3, Flex 4.5 and AIR 2.6 with TextMate on Mac OS X.

i've found several posts concerning required bundles, but most of the threads are a few years old in addition to having convoluted, sparse instructions for setting up.

it seems that auto-complete and .swc files are supported, which is great.  in addition to instructions i'm also very interested in learning about what isn't supported and other common pitfalls.

i've been familiarizing myself with TextMate's UI and it's amazing.  i would much rather use it than Flash Builder / Eclipse, or even Flash Professional.

one last question - i understand that it's possible to set up our own keyboard shortcuts to compile with MXMLC and write the .swf to disk.  is it possible to have the .swf auto open in Flash Player Debugger after it is compiled.  essentially, i'd like to continue using Command+Enter shortcut for testing movies in Flash Professional to build and launch since i would certain have a difficult time adjusting to new muscle memory.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Grab the Flex 4 SDK, its documentation and the Flex 3 documentation.
2. Grab [the latest actionscript3.tmbundle](https://github.com/simongregory/actionscript3-tmbundle) and install it.
3. Hit <kbd>help</kbd> and read the help, it explains where to put what and how to configure your environment.
4. For some reason I can't make it work with the Flex 4 documentation but the Flex 3 one works. YMMV.

Even after all of this, TextMate — with all its sexyness — will still be very inferior to Flash Develop: the autocomplete part is very "alpha" and is not "auto" at all, for example.

For the debugging part, I just open the .html with Safari and read the debugging information written to `~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/Logs/flashlog.txt` either in the Terminal or in Console.app.

Good luck and feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: i plan on doing mostly AIR development rather than web site development.  any idea if it's possible with TextMate?  also, what about trace statements or runtime errors?   where do they appear?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience in AIR dev. I can't help you on that. When using the debug version of the Flash plugin, the trace statements and runtime errors appear in the file indicated in my last paragraph. I have no idea if such a mecanism exists for AIR. There are a couple of abandoned/stalled easy-to-find-via-google bundles available [here](https://github.com/libin/Air.tmbundle) and [here](http://remysharp.com/2008/04/09/air-textmate-bundle/), though. Please, consider writing a detailed step by step answer if you succeed. It may help you and others.